# interactive Shell print function showing SyntaxError: invalid syntax

Tags: python, python-3.x

Hello everyone I was working on a exercise and also new to the syntax of the use of python. I tried to write this code to show the Max Number:

```
def maxNum(a,c):
    if a>c:
        return a
    else:
        return c
        
print(maxNum(16,20))
```

a little background when I use `maxNum(16,20)` or `print(maxNum(16,20))` I get a SyntaxError: invalid syntax in the interactive shell however when I use a new window and run the above script the answer 20 is shown.  Why is it the above script has to be ran from a new window and not in the shell it to work? In addition is there a website that shows when or how to indent? Thanks

Comment: You may want to learn a few things from python tutorial websites or youtube. https://www.w3schools.com/python/ , https://www.tutorialspoint.com/python/index.htm, https://www.learnpython.org/, https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=WGJJIrtnfpk are a few examples

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to validate the function definition by pressing  **[ENTER]** and then put the rest of code

```
def maxNum(a,c):
    if a>c:
        return a
    else:
        return c
        

print(maxNum(16,20))
```

[image]

Comment: The problem is the extra whitespace. You may not have noticed it, but the interpreter sure did.

Comment: lol it sure did.  Thanks for the information.  It worked. I know moving forward.   I have a follow up question I took the white space out and pressed Enter and for some reason the error SyntaxError: invalid syntax still showed.  Why would it now allow everything in the function?  Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You have extra spaces on the apparently empty line between the end of the function definition and the `print` call. With that, the interpreter is expecting more content in the function. To end a compound statement in an interactive session, you need two linefeeds in a row.

Comment: I went back over the information one more time and it cleared up my question.  Thanks.